# Flattening Java Bean to a Map

Tags: java, javabeans, apache-commons

I am stuck at converting `Java Bean` to `Map`. There are many resources on the internet, but unfortunately they all treat converting simple beans to Maps. My ones are a little bit more extensive.

There's simplified example:

```
public class MyBean {

  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private MyHomeAddress homeAddress;
  private int age;

  // getters & setters

}
```

My point is to produce `Map<String, Object>` which, in this case, is true for following conditions:

```
map.containsKey("firstName")
map.containsKey("lastName")
map.containsKey("homeAddress.street")  // street is String
map.containsKey("homeAddress.number")  // number is int
map.containsKey("homeAddress.city")    // city is String
map.containsKey("homeAddress.zipcode") // zipcode is String
map.containsKey("age")
```

I have tried using `Apache Commons BeanUtils`. Both approaches `BeanUtils#describe(Object)` and `BeanMap(Object)` produce a Map which "deep level" is 1 (I mean that there's only `"homeAddress"` key, holding `MyHomeAddress` object as a value). My method should enter the objects deeper and deeper until it meets a primitive type (or String), then it should stop digging and insert key i.e. `"order.customer.contactInfo.home"`.

So, my question is: how can it be easliy done (or is there already existing project which would allow me to do that)?

**update**

I have expanded Radiodef answer to include also Collections, Maps Arrays and Enums:

```
private static boolean isValue(Object value) {
  final Class<?> clazz = value.getClass();
  if (value == null ||
      valueClasses.contains(clazz) ||
      Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) ||
      Map.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) ||
      value.getClass().isArray() ||
      value.getClass().isEnum()) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You probably don't mean "primitive", since `String` isn't a primitive (it extends `Object`).  So you'd need a way to tell the algorithm which classes to traverse, and which to take as values, so there probably isn't going to be a way to do this without some sort of configuration (maybe using annotations).

Comment: This can be done with reflection and recursion, you just almost certainly have to write it yourself. Note that at the moment the question will get closed because asking for library recommendations is off-topic.

Comment: Tonio, Radiodef - thanks for your suggestions, I have edited my post.

Comment: Hi, typically I run into situations where I would want to map a bean to a transfer object. The situation often arises when creating page objects for display or for some way to change a structure from one to another. In those cases I use something like Dozer or ModelMapper that allow for mapping with various approaches such as xml, api or annotation based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a simple reflective/recursive example.

You should be aware that there are some issues with doing a conversion the way you've asked:

- Map keys must be unique.
- Java allows classes to name their private fields the same name as a private field owned by an inherited class.

This example doesn't address those because I'm not sure how you want to account for them (if you do). If your beans inherit from something other than `Object`, you will need to change your idea a little bit. This example only considers the fields of the subclass.

In other words, if you have

```
public class SubBean extends Bean {
```

this example will only return fields from `SubBean`.

Java lets us do this:

```
package com.acme.util;
public class Bean {
    private int value;
}

package com.acme.misc;
public class Bean extends com.acme.util.Bean {
    private int value;
}
```

Not that anybody should be doing that, but it's a problem if you want to use `String` as the keys, because there would be two keys named `"value"`.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import java.util.*;

public final class BeanFlattener {
    private BeanFlattener() {}

    public static Map<String, Object> deepToMap(Object bean) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        try {
            putValues(bean, map, null);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException x) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(x);
        }
        return map;
    }

    private static void putValues(Object bean,
                                  Map<String, Object> map,
                                  String prefix)
            throws IllegalAccessException {
        Class<?> cls = bean.getClass();

        for (Field field : cls.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.isSynthetic() || Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
                continue;
            field.setAccessible(true);

            Object value = field.get(bean);
            String key;
            if (prefix == null) {
                key = field.getName();
            } else {
                key = prefix + "." + field.getName();
            }

            if (isValue(value)) {
                map.put(key, value);
            } else {
                putValues(value, map, key);
            }
        }
    }

    private static final Set<Class<?>> VALUE_CLASSES =
        Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(
            Object.class,    String.class, Boolean.class,
            Character.class, Byte.class,   Short.class,
            Integer.class,   Long.class,   Float.class,
            Double.class
            // etc.
        )));

    private static boolean isValue(Object value) {
        return value == null
            || value instanceof Enum<?>
            || VALUE_CLASSES.contains(value.getClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this implementation works like a charm. I have expanded `isValue(Object)` method to also include another classes which were needed in my project (see my post).

Comment: Thank you for great piece of code @Radiodef. I have written some unit tests for this code,and I am planning to use it in an Api, I was wondering that does anybody face with some bug in this very code?

Comment: @AngelThread Just glancing over my code here again and the only obvious problem I see is that it will cause a `StackOverflowError` or `OutOfMemoryError` if it's passed an object which contains a circular reference, for example `class A { B b; }` and `class B { A a; }`. Such an object might not be considered a bean, but if I were to write this method over again I'd handle cases like that. I think you'd have a `Set<Object> values;` and every time you add a field which isn't a value type you'd first check the `Set` to see if the value has already been added. If it's in the set, you don't recurse.

Comment: @Radiodef Thank you for further support, I think in the same way about objects in your example can not be seen as beans, but I am going to consider cases like that.

Answer (score 5):

You could always use the [Jackson Json Processor](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). Like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
//...
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
//...
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.convertValue(pojo, Map.class);
```

where pojo is some Java bean. You can use some nice annotations on the bean to control the serialization.

You can re-use the ObjectMapper.

Comment: convertValue() method doesn't flatten inner objects, for example I have a Cat class which has an attribute is called friend and this attribute is also Cat type. If I convert instance of Cat class with convertValue method, it will be like following.                                                                                              {friend={friend=null, childCount=2, name=yellow}, childCount=1, name=red}

Comment: @AngelThread Flattening is not performed, but inner objects may be converted depending on their type (For example, inner maps). And it is possible to configure Jackson to create a Map hierarchy as well, but that is outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for further contribution on this, I was trying to show a side of this piece of code.

Comment: I want to compliment the author of the post for providing not only the name of the class, but also the name of the package. Alas, very few authors do that. +1