# How can I flatten a complex Java Bean and convert between the flat Bean and the original?

Tags: java, javabeans, dozer

I have a Java bean that has hundreds of fields, each of which can recursively be a different with fields and more sub-beans. My problem is that I need to load values from a flat file with field name/value pairs, but I don't have the fully-qualified name of the field.

Suppose I have classes A and B. A contains an instance of B, and B contains a String field named `f` which stores value `s`.  If the instance of each class is just the lowercase class name, the fully-qualified name of `f` within this data structure is `a.b.f`

Effectively, I need to do something as shown below, only I'm actually using reflection since I read the field name from a file.

...
a.getB().setF(x); // this is an oversimplification; I would also need to create and assign an instance of B if a.b is null.

However, what I really want to be able to do is a simple a.setF(s).

Assuming there are no duplicate fields across all beans, how can I generate a flattened bean and convert between the two?

A colleague mentioned [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net), which sounds like it could work for the conversion from the flat bean format to the hierarchical bean format, but it looks like I would still need to generate the flattened bean and the mapping. Since there are hundreds of fields and dozens of beans, this is definitely something I don't want to have to do manually.

Comment: Reflection and some code generation?

Comment: @DaveNewton I forgot to mention it but that's what I'm also currently thinking; I wasn't sure if there was already some ready-to-go library or code so I don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @rob can you share example of your source flat data file? what is name conventional here? what are possible data formats?

Comment: If for any reason you want to do it by hand [here's how converting to flat bean (map) can work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25627913/flattening-java-bean-to-a-map)

Comment: You could try either of these approaches, perhaps:

http://simple.sourceforge.net/

OR

http://beanio.org/

Or just use reflection and roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

I think your flattening problem can be solved in these steps

1. load all your data in a simple `Map<String, String>` into memory. Usual java `Properties` can be used for this.
2. scan the map keys and automatically prepare Dozer's in mapper configuration (e.g. with a name `builder`) with a help of [Dozer Java API](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/apimappings.html). E.g. automatically create `BeanMappingBuilder` for this.
3. call Dozer for real conversion:

`DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
mapper.addMapping(builder);
HugeDestinationalBean result = mapper.map(properties, HugeDestinationalBean.class);`

Here `HugeDestinationalBean` is your target bean.

The trickiest part, obviously, is the step 2. Its implementation depends of field naming conventional in your source data file and structure of your target bean.

Alternatively, implement the step 2 manually on a base of usual Java Reflection.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Dozer; would you please expand your exmaple to walk through reading data from a flat file into a nested bean?